# Outlook custom notification, and have full control on the buttons

Tags: outlook

Anyone had an idea, or advice or guide. How i can make some custom notification like the image below? I want to have two buttons on it and i have full controller on that button when clicked

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a COM (VSTO) addin (rather than JS), you can display a custom WinForms or WPF window with any custom controls.